# Weird spots on my kittens face

Tags: cats, diseases

Hi few days ago my cat had a dark spot in his face, on the nose side.

Thought it was dirt from eating so leave it.

But today seen an identical one in the other nose side, so I get worried.

[image]
[image]

Any kind of symptom?
Thank you!

Comment: Are they crunchy (if dried) or sticky (if still wet), and wipe off easily?

Comment: Hi, there are two vertical line-wipeoff not so far from the commissures. It are dried, it seems to be "cat acne"; Have been negligent and not cleaned the water and foot dishes in days. Now have applied infusion of field horsetail, as it is a natural desinfectant. What you think?